# Calling non static method in static context(main)

Tags: static, non-static

I know that non static methods cannot be referenced from some static context, you have to make an instance of the class and call the method on that instance, or , you can make the method static. I also know the reason why. But I cannot decide what is the best practice to do this? Making the method/variable static or using instance of the class to call the method/variable, and why?

Comment: Depends on requirement. Give us scenario you have to which you can't decide and update the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object oriented languages work best when you use objects. If its anything more than the most basic of applications, create a class to house the functionality and instantiate it.  You'll just end up refactoring into classes later anyway.

The reason is that objects, instances, etc all describe varying degrees of scope, allowing you to create complex programs from an amalgamation of encapsulated, fairly simple functionalities